# How to set gmail auto forwarding rule through gmail API in javascript(React Native)?

Tags: gmail-api

I need to send an automatic email forward to another email address like Gmail.

> Can I set auto-forwarding rules through Gmail API integration in my application?

Comment: Please edit your question show us what you have tried and desscribe any issues with your current solution

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by using [Method: users.settings.updateAutoForwarding](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings/updateAutoForwarding).

**Request method:** `PUT`

**Path:** [https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/settings/autoForwarding](https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%7BuserId%7D/settings/autoForwarding)

**Request body:**

```
{
  "enabled": boolean,
  "emailAddress": string,
  "disposition": enum (Disposition)
}
```

### Reference:

[Auto Forwarding Request Body](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/AutoForwarding)